# django save custom value in automatic primary key auto_increment

Tags: django, primary-key

I have a django model with a default primary key which is autoincrementing.

My situation is that I want to create an instance having a custom id, see the example below :

let's say we had the following instances represented by their respective ids :

```
instance_a(id=1), instance_b(id=2), instance_c(id=3), instance_d(id=4), instance_e(id=5)
```

let's say instance_c has been deleted so the list becomes :

```
instance_a(id=1), instance_b(id=2), instance_d(id=4), instance_e(id=5)
```

And now I want to create instance_f with id=3 which is the id of the previously deleted instace. So the list should become :

```
instance_a(id=1), instance_b(id=2), instance_f(id=3), instance_d(id=4), instance_e(id=5)
```

I tried setting the id in the request but it always gives an automatic autoincrement id.

Please do you know a way to achieve this. I hope my explanation was clear.

Comment: Please *don't* do this. This means that an url that originally was assigned to the "old" object, now will refer to the new object. This means thus that people who bookmarked an item, no see something they did not bookmarked.

Comment: A primary key should be seen as a "blackbox" token. Just something to identify the object, but knowledge of the "shape" of that token.

Comment: it's not something public it's something i have to do, i know that it may be a wrong practice but it's the only way i can achieve my usecase. I'm doing it because i have not found a solution to changing a subclass of a model to another subclass thus i'm deleting the instance and recreating it with the same id.

Comment: `instance_b(id=2).save()` or `instance_b.id = 2 && instance_b.save()` should work (although not safe for duplicate or already existing id values). What is the problem with these approaches?

Comment: @nassim: this is the XY problem. You have a problem X, but you ask for a solution for another problem Y. I suggest that you share the details the real (underlying) problem, such that help is more effective.

Comment: @ElginCahangirov the solution you present gives rise to the problem that now you may cause the sequence that produces the id's to get out of sync. This is another reason you should not do this in addition to the ones given above by Willem

Comment: I agree with Willem, this is not a good practice and you shouldn't do that if you can. But maybe this thoughts could be useful for you. Don't delete the items, but mark them deleted instead. And when you need to create new item, just replace the very first marked-as-deleted item with new data. Then ids will be saved and new items will be placed on the old items places.